# Fields vanished in node edit form

Tags: 7, entities

In node edit form, I am not able to see any other fields other than body field. Though the field values are displayed in the node view page.

For debugging, I tried to print the form value in form alter. To my surprise, all the fields are displayed in the form with `#access` true. I even checked the DOM if I have hided the fields by mistake, but there were no field markup in the DOM either. I checked all this as the drupal super admin.

The only major change I did in recent time was enabling https for the site. Has anyone faced something similar? Can anyone suggest on how to debug this issue?

Comment: switch to the default drupal theme and see if you can see them then.

Comment: I was using Seven theme as my admin theme, I changed it to Bartik still I can't see them.